# Access variable from another class that was passed in constructor

Tags: php, oop

I'm coding a WP plugin using PHP OOP. I'm passing some classes to my main class, so that I will be able to access variables and methods from my main class to other classes. In fact I'm able to access methods, but not variables. For example we have `Main` and `Secondary` classes:

```
class Main {
    public $secondary;

    public function __construct($secondary) {
        $this->secondary= $secondary;
    }

    public function methodFromSecondary() {
        echo $this->secondary->secondaryMethod();
    }

    public function variableFromSecondary() {
        echo $this->secondary->secondaryVariable;
    }
}

class Secondary {
   public $secondaryVariable;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->secondaryVariable = 'some variable string';
   }

   public function secondaryMethod() {
       return 'some mothod string';
   }
}

$secondary = new Secondary();
$main = new Main($secondary);
```

If I call `$main->methodFromSecondary()` it outputs `'some mothod string'` and if I call `$main->variableFromSecondary()`, WP outputs that site is experiencing technical issues. So how can I access a variable to output `'some variable string'` as I access method?

Comment: not sure why what you have is not working but you could create `public function secondaryVariable() {return $this->secondaryVariable;}` and then use that method to get it that way..

Comment: Is this the actual code that’s giving you trouble, or just an example?

Comment: @JacobPeattie No, actual code is much more complicated, but this part is not working.

Comment: Have you reduced your actual code to this test case? It’s impossible for anyone here to help debug code that they can’t see.

Comment: @JacobPeattie so this should work, and problem is in something else?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. First thing that comes to. Ind is to make sure that the variable in question is not private or protected.

Comment: @JacobPeattie All right, Thanks!

Comment: I used both methods with success from the Main class. Everything worked fine.